# How to code vba with reference to selenium for clicking the close button of the pop up in edge browser that is modal based

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, microsoft-edge

I would like to create an excel macro to automate the data upload into government site and then retrieve a QR code png in return to put into the worksheet after data are swiftly processed from their end. I'm a newbie here.

I am stuck in the early stage where I could not state the correct element for the close button or the "tutup pengumuman" button in the pop-up overlay. The website will refresh every 60s. I have tried the below but to no avail:

Hopefully there is someone who can advise on my problem here. Thanks!

```
    Public Sub selenium()
        Dim bot As New WebDriver
        bot.Start "edge", "https://simka-outbreak.moh.gov.my/outbreak/index.php"
        bot.Get "/"
        bot.Window.Maximize
        bot.Wait 100000
        bot.FindElementById("myModal2").Click
        bot.FindElementByClass("close").Click
        bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='myModal2']/div/div/div[1]/button").Click
        bot.FindElementByClass("btn btn-primary").Click
        bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='myModal2']/div/div/div[2]/center/b/button").Click
        bot.FindElementById("username").SendKeys ("username")
        bot.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("password")
        bot.FindElementById("submitBtn").Click
        bot.Wait 1000000
    End Sub
```

html as below:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Pengumuman Penting</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                
                <b><font color=blue>PENUTUPAN KHIDMAT BANTUAN PENGGUNA MELALUI WHATSAPP</font></b>
<br><br>
Tuan/Puan Yang Dihormati
<br><br>
Merujuk kepada perkara diatas, <font color=red><b>khidmat bantuan pengguna melalui Whatsapp ditutup buat sementara waktu</b></font>.<br><br>Sila emel ke it.mkak@moh.gov.my atau hubungi 03-6126-1200 (Hari Isnin hingga Jumaat dari jam 9pagi hingga 5petang sahaja) untuk sebarang bantuan.<br><br>Terima kasih diatas kesabaran pihak tuan/puan.<b><br><br>




<br> 


<!--
<b><font color=blue>HEBAHAN KEMASKINI PEMBOLEHUBAH SIMKA OUTBREAK</font></b>
<br><br>
Tuan/Puan Yang Dihormati
<br><br>
Mohon muat turun kemaskini terbaru bertarikh <font color=red><b>18hb Mei 2021</b></font> untuk maklumat Pemboleh Ubah SIMKA Outbreak<b><br><br>

Sila muat turun dokumen berkaitan dengan mengklik link <a href="https://simka-outbreak.moh.gov.my/HebahanKemaskiniPembolehUbahSimka.pdf" target="_blank">DI SINI</a></b>.<br><br>

<br><br>

<br>-->


                </p><center>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup Pengumuman</button>
            </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `bot.SwitchToAlert.accept`

Comment: Thanks. Just tried with both accept and dismiss and both didn't work

Comment: Hi @user16717362 How about the issue? Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872373/how-to-code-vba-with-reference-to-selenium-for-clicking-the-close-button-of-the/68905664#68905664) below helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors do you have when you run your code? Why you wait for 100000ms so long? I made a test with wait for 5000ms and `bot.FindElementByClass("close").Click` and it can work well.

You can refer to the following code example:

```
Public Sub Selenium()
        Dim bot As New WebDriver
        bot.Start "edge", "https://simka-outbreak.moh.gov.my/outbreak/index.php"
        bot.Get "/"
        bot.Window.Maximize
        bot.Wait 5000
        bot.FindElementByClass("close").Click
        bot.FindElementById("username").SendKeys ("username")
        bot.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("password")
        bot.FindElementById("submitBtn").Click
        bot.Wait 5000
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `class name` for `Tutup Pengumuman` button has a `space`. When tried with below line, it worked.

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]").click()
```